# How to add onClick to this?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

**Hello everyone**, I think I have an easy problem to solve.
 My problem is that it dosent work onClickListener.

**After clicking on the item, I want to open a new activity**

I searched the forum and implemented different combinations with TEXT VIEW but nothing works..

xml code "drawermenu"

```
    <item android:id="@+id/db" android:title="Moje Konto" android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_white_24px"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/event" android:title="Imprezy" android:icon="@drawable/ic_party_dj"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/serach" android:title="Szukaj" android:icon="@drawable/ic_smartphone"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/settings" android:title="Lista Klubow" android:icon="@drawable/ic_list" />
    <item android:id="@+id/activities" android:title="Ustawienia" android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/logout" android:title="Wyloguj" android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit"/>
```

MAIN Activity

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    if (mToggle!!.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {

        R.id.db -> {

        }
        R.id.event -> {

        }
        R.id.serach -> {

        }
        R.id.settings -> {
            var intent= Intent(this, ListaKlub::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        R.id.activities -> {

        }
    }

    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

}

activity main xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/darkgrey"
app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
android:layout_gravity="start"

/>
```

THANKS FOR HELP!

App Photo

[image: App Photo]

Comment: i think you implement onOptionsItemSelected..not onClickListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use navigationView reference and then do something like this:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
         when (it.itemId) {
             R.id.nav_home -> {
               // handle click true 
            } else -> false 

         } 
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: 1 error
"onNavigationItemSelected" override nothing
i add to R.id.xyz -> intent to open new activity

Comment: where you have defined xyz id?

Comment: look at the post :/ update dont know why i have that error,

Comment: try adding navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    when (it.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home -> {
            // handle click
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}